# How to use jenkins use environment variables in parameters in a Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use "JOB_BASE_NAME" jenkins environmental variable in a parameter's path in a pipeline script that gets set will building the project.

example: string(defaultValue: "/abc/test/workspace/test_${JOB_BASE_NAME}/sample", description: 'test', name: 'HOME')

but while executing the ${JOB_BASE_NAME} is not getting replaced by the value(jenkins job name). I'm unsure if I'm setting the jenkins environmental variable in the path of the parameter correctly.

thank you!

Comment: We need to see how you are both assigning the environment value and how you are resolving its value.

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated your use case and it works for me. This is the section of code

```
node {
   stage ('test') {
       sh "echo ${HOME}"
   }
}
```

and this is the output - (my Job name was stackoverflow)

```
[Pipeline] { (hide)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo /abc/test/workspace/test_stackoverflow/sample
/abc/test/workspace/test_stackoverflow/sample
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Check the picture of how I set the String parameter.

[image]

Comment: thanks but I need to store the value of the ${JOB_BASE_NAME} so I can use it in other string parameters that will be used during run time.

Comment: JOB_BASE_NAME is a Jenkins variable which can be accessed anywhere.

Comment: thanks @Pankaj When I set it as a string parameter the job fails saying" FSUM6404 directory "/abc/test/workspace/test_${JOB_BASE_NAME}/sample": EDC5129I No such file or directory." Looks like the job name is not getting replaced with the value. I set the string parameter in the pipeline like this 
 parameters {
string(defaultValue: "/abc/test/workspace/test_${JOB_BASE_NAME}/sample", description: 'test', name: 'HOME') }